# How do I convert this foldl to foldr for laziness sake?

Tags: haskell, vector, linear-algebra, lazy-evaluation

I have written a function that computes an orthogonal matrix via the Gram-Schmidt method from an input matrix. However, I'm aware that to utilize laziness I should use `foldr`, but I'm having a hard time converting the `foldl'`. The `reverse` is also definitely ruining laziness, but its need might disappear with the use of `foldr`.

Is there a procedure I can follow to achieve this, perhaps?

```hs
import Data.List (foldl', transpose)
import Debug.Trace (traceShowId)
import Prelude hiding (subtract)

type Vector = [Double]

type Column = Vector

type Row = Vector

type Matrix = [Vector]

unitVectors :: Matrix -> [Vector]
unitVectors m =
  let cs = transpose m
   in reverse $ 
        foldl' (\normcols col -> normalize (foldl' subtract col [q `scale` (q .* col) | q <- normcols]) : normcols) [] cs

euclidlen :: [Double] -> Double
euclidlen = sqrt . foldr (\x xs -> x ^ 2 + xs) 0

subtract :: Vector -> Vector -> Vector
subtract = zipWith (-)

infixl 7 .*

-- dot product
(.*) :: Row -> Column -> Double
r .* c = sum $ zipWith (*) r c

-- scale a vector
scale :: Vector -> Double -> Vector
v1 `scale` n = map (* n) v1

-- normalize a vector
normalize :: Vector -> Vector
normalize v = map (/ euclidlen v) v
```

Comment: Note that your function is already pretty lazy.  Try:  `head $ unitVectors [[1,undefined],[1,undefined]]`.  Do you have an example where it isn't lazy enough for your tastes?

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Actually, no! I find it hard to measure how lazy it is, so I've mainly trying to stick to principles. But you might be right, it could be lazy enough already.

Comment: @K.A.Buhr Although your example fails, maybe it isn't plausible to make this function more lazy.